# Heroku app drops initial requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Whenever I hit my application on Heroku for the first time (over a period of about 10 minutes), it fails. Something went wrong error. But a refresh, always fixes the problem? Any ideas what might be causing this? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Easiest way to solve this problem of keeping apps alive in general (i.e. not just on Heroku) is set up a simple cron job fetch the page every 10 minutes or so. just add to your crontab something like "*/10 * * * * curl http://yourapp.com"

Answer (score 11):

If you are running with 1 dyno (the free way) then your dyno will shut down after some period of inactivity and get started back up upon the next request. So, when you leave it alone for 10 minutes it gets shutdown and tries to spin back up on that first request. That process is usually pretty fast and you will see a 3-5 sec startup lag but not enough to time you out.

Do you have anything going on during startup that would take a long time?

Also, if it is worth paying a little bit per month you can bump it up to 2 dynos and they will not spin it down on paid apps.

Comment: are you sure it's a 10 min inactivity timer or... ? I'm pretty interested in the actual number here.

Answer (score 7):

I was having the same issue when I added  the compass framework to my application. In my error logs I was getting this error:

Errno::EACCES (Permission denied - /app/public/stylesheets/screen.css)

Following these instructions solved the problem

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-compass

Answer (score 4):

To build on @Ben's answer, which is 100% correct, there's one issue: it doesn't seen you're getting a timeout error. The "Something Went Wrong" error indicates a 500 error, so your app is being loaded, but something is throwing an exception. If it only happens on the first request, then there is something that is being loaded/executed only on the first request which is causing the problem.

If this is the case, then to see the error, check your logs:

```
$ heroku logs
```

Or sign-up for an error-reporting add-on, like Exceptional (it's free!):

```
$ heroku addons:add exceptional
```

You can then access Exceptional from your Heroku dashboard for your app - once there, use the "Add-ons" menu in the upper-right.

Answer (score 1):

This has happened to me on all my apps for the past couple years. I never was annoying enough to really figure it out until now.

In my logs on the first request, I get this: Errno::EACCES (Permission denied - /app/public/stylesheets/screen.css)

The second, and sequential, requests work fine without this error. I can't think of anything wrong with my screen.css file.